# Haskell Data.Unique

Tags: haskell, unique, io-monad

I need to rename variables for an application where I am unifying terms, and the way I have done it in the past has been to use (gensym)-like features, and replace the name of the var with the gensym-ed name, usually mangled to a string. I also need to compare the names of variables.

so `(rename (logvar1 "foo"))` would return `(logvar1 "#:23322)` - or whatever, and I can get hold of the "#:23322" and check it against any other logical vars in the terms.

In haskell, I am not sure how to do that. I have found Data.Unique, which returns a IO Unique.
Unique is part of Eq, but of course IO Unique isn't.

What is the best way to write this function

```
m = newUnique
n = newUnique

test :: (Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m a -> m Bool
test u1 u2 = do
  v1 <- u1
  v2 <- u2
  if v1 == v2 then return True else return False
```

I would like True of False back, not IO True or IO False.

Of course, you can't always get what you want.....

I'm grateful for any help. I understand why the IO is there, I'm just not sure how best do deal with it in the rest of my program where I just want to compare

Answer (score 2):

The idea of this library is that in the part of your program where you need to generate unique labels, you use IO. Later, when you only need to compare unique labels, no IO is needed

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- newUnique
  y <- newUnique
  print $ same x y

same :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
same = (==)
```

I've defined an alias for `(==)` just to make it clear that there is no IO involved in comparisons, only in label creation.

You could do the same thing using State instead of IO, and implementing your own gensym with that. The advantage of that approach would be that you could get more transparent gensyms, e.g. giving them a name and a unique number instead of just an opaque unique identifier.

Comment: Thank you very much - given that newUnique returns IO Unique, how would I then compare the unique values in pure code? I thought that I would always be in the IO monad when operating on the values - thanks again

Comment: @user2162871 you shift the paradigm and have your pure functions work "inside" the  IO computation. Your pure functions will receive new identifier names as arguments, like `same` does in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `test` signature makes sense. You shouldn't compare monadic values – that would be comparing *generators* of unique values, not unique values themselves.

You *do* need a monad for generating the unique keys, because a non-monadic generator could not know about other ones that have already been generated; however doing this in `IO` is a bit overkill, a dedicated special monad would be better.
[`prim-uniq` offers such generators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prim-uniq-0.2/docs/Data-Unique-Prim.html): they can be used either in `IO` like `Data.Unique.newUnique`, but also locally in the `ST` monad.

```
type VarId s = Uniq s

data Expr s = LogVar (VarIs s)
            | ...
  deriving (Eq)

rename :: (PrimMonad m, s ~ PrimState m)
              => Expr s -> m (Expr s)
rename (LogVar _) = LogVar <$> getUniq
rename ... = ...
```

Comment: Thank you - very helpful. If I was in pure code and needed to see if 2 Vars had the same "Id" - how would I do that? I  understand what you are saying about comparing IO Unique. But how should I compare 2 vars to see if they have the same ID, given that both IDs are IO Unique (or in ST)? I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: You only ever store the `Uniq s` values, not `ST s (Uniq s)`. I.e., like in amalloy's answer you always first bind them them with `x <- get Uniq`. So, you not exactly writing pure code but monadic code (like you do when doing this in an impure language). But by working in the `ST` monad instead of `IO`, you're still guaranteed not to have any global side-effects.